# package image works in style but not in img

Tags: html, css, cordova, ngcordova, html5-filesystem

I am using ng-cordova, I have stored an image in a subdirectory of `cordova.file.dataDirectory`, and am unable to load it via `img[src]` but I can load it via `[style]`, do I have to do anything special to make it work in the `img[src]`?

**$scope**

```
{
"Image":"file:///data/data/{package}/files/{subdir}/{imagename}.png"
}
```

**Works**

```
<div style="background-image:url({{Image}})"></div>
```

**Doesn't work**

```
<img src="{{Image}}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly error, I forgot to check my `$compileProvider` service. I had it working for `filesystem` but not `file`.

```
$compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|local|data|filesystem|file):/);
```